# How to change url naming convention in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a guitar lessons site. It has hierarchy categories->lesson->exercise

Currently the urls appear like this:

```
Category: /category/1/somecat

Lesson: /lesson/1/some-title

Exercise: /exercise/1/some-title
```

There are a number of places where this naming is hard coded, such as view folder names, views, routes, etc.

This is what I really want:

```
Category: /guitar-lesson-category/1/somecat

Lesson: /guitar-lesson/1/some-title

Exercise: /guitar-lesson-exercise/1/some-title
```

I feel this will be better for google search if I am interested in phrase guitar lessons.

Here are some entries from the routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/category/{id}/{name?}', 'CategoryController@category');

Route::get('/lesson/{id}/{name?}', 'LessonController@index');
Route::post('/lesson/hit/{id}', 'LessonController@hit');
Route::post('/lesson/progress/{id}', 'LessonController@progress');
Route::post('/lesson/favorite/{id}', 'LessonController@favorite');

Route::get('/exercise/{id}/{name?}', 'ExerciseController@index');
Route::post('/exercise/hit/{id}', 'ExerciseController@hit');
Route::post('/exercise/progress/{id}', 'ExerciseController@progress');
Route::post('/exercise/favorite/{id}', 'ExerciseController@favorite');
```

Any idea how to do this as painlessly as possible? Specific examples of what to edit and how would be appreciated!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
////Route Group Example
//Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
//    Route::get('users', function () {
//        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
//    });
//});

//Solution For You
Route::prefix('/category')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index');
        // Matches The "/category" URL
    Route::get('/{id}/{name?}', 'CategoryController@category');
        // Matches The "/category/{id}/{name?}" URL
});

Route::prefix('/lesson')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{id}/{name?}', 'LessonController@index');
        // Matches The "/lesson/{id}/{name?}" URL
    Route::post('/hit/{id}', 'LessonController@hit');
        // Matches The "/lesson/hit/{id}" URL
    Route::post('/progress/{id}', 'LessonController@progress');
        // Matches The "/lesson/progress/{id}" URL
    Route::post('/favorite/{id}', 'LessonController@favorite');
        // Matches The "/lesson/favorite/{id}" URL
});

Route::prefix('/exercise')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{id}/{name?}', 'ExerciseController@index');
        // Matches The "/exercise/{id}/{name?}" URL
    Route::post('/hit/{id}', 'ExerciseController@hit');
        // Matches The "/exercise/hit/{id}" URL
    Route::post('/progress/{id}', 'ExerciseController@progress');
        // Matches The "/exercise/progress/{id}" URL
    Route::post('/favorite/{id}', 'ExerciseController@favorite');
        // Matches The "/exercise/favorite/{id}" URL
});
```

Comment: Hi, I don't see how this would produce the url naming convention that I specified.